# Add ranking to query output

Tags: mysql, rank

I'm new at programming with PHP/mySQL and I have got a little problem here.

This is how my code looks like:

```
SELECT  
 COUNT(*) AS Number , Name 
FROM 
 table 
GROUP BY 
 Name 
ORDER BY 
 Number DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

Out of this table:

```
Oliver
Michael
Oliver
Steven
Michael
Oliver
Oliver
```

... it generates:

```
Oliver  | 4
Michael | 2
Steven  | 1
```

My question: How can I add ranking numbers so that it looks like this:

```
1 | Oliver  | 4
2 | Michael | 2
3 | Steven  | 1
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Questions :Q1) Suppose Oliver and Michael have 4. Would the ranking be : `1 Oliver 4`, `1 Michael 4`, `3 Steven 1` or  `1 Oliver 4`, `2 Michael 4`, `3 Steven 1` ? Q2) Suppose Michael and Steven had 2. Would the ranking be :  `1 Oliver 4`, `2 Michael 2`, `3 Steven 2` or  `1 Oliver 4`, `2 Michael 2`, `2 Steven 1` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  state, num_cities, @n := @n+1 AS rank
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  state, count(*) AS num_cities
            FROM  us
            GROUP BY  state
            ORDER BY  num_cities DESC 
      ) AS x
    JOIN  
      ( SELECT  @n:=0 ) AS init

+-------+------------+------+
| state | num_cities | rank |
+-------+------------+------+
| CA    |        447 |    1 |
| FL    |        264 |    2 |
| TX    |        238 |    3 |
| IL    |        221 |    4 |
| NY    |        185 |    5 |
| OH    |        185 |    6 |
| MA    |        180 |    7 |
```